# Proof of $\left(\sum_{n=0}^{s}\{(s-n)F_Z(s-n)-n\lambda F_Z(s-n-1)\}\{P_N(n)-2P_N(n-1)+P_N(n-2)\}\right)\geq 0$

Tags: probability-theory, summation, stochastic-processes

I have two Poisson random variables;
$$P_Z(z)=\frac{(n\lambda)^{z}}{z!}e^{-n\lambda}, \quad z=0,1,2,3,...$$
$$P_N(n)=\frac{\mu^{n}}{n!}e^{-\mu},\quad  n=0,1,2,3,...$$

I would like to prove 
$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^{s}\{(s-n)F_Z(s-n)-n\lambda F_Z(s-n-1)\}\{P_N(n)-2P_N(n-1)+P_N(n-2)\}\right)\geq 0$$
where $F_Z(x)=\sum_{z=0}^x P_Z(z)$ is the cumulative distribution function of $Z$ at $x$.

Comment: Is there any motivation or context for this problem?

Comment: @ Math1000 Yes, for sure. It comes from a compound Poisson random variable, but since it was so complicated, I summarized it in the presented form.